# What is the use of negative right margin on left floated divs in CSS?

Tags: html, css

What does a negative right margin do if two divs inside a parent div container are floated left ? I have heard of a common scenario where it can be used to solve a common problem where it is required for 2 floats to be side-by-side and to stretch to 100% width but where one float has a fixed pixel width. But apparently I am not getting the picture. 
I am a newbie to CSS so it would be very helpful if someone can explain me from the scratch. 
Please note that I am somehow aware of the effects of negative margins on the statically positioned elements just I am not clear of the question asked above.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)'s column system is a nice example of this.

Take this code sample:

```
<div class="container">
    <header class="header">Header goes here</header>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6"><div class="box">Image 1</div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"><div class="box">Image 2</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With some styling, this gets you this:

[image]
*Pink is the container padding and lightgreen is the column padding.*

The columns are both 50% and have 15px padding. If you want them to be properly aligned with the header, you'll have to clear the `padding-left` of the left column, and the `padding-right` of the right column. This is not a very good workaround. What if you want to switch to smaller columns on a larger viewport?

Luckily, there is a better way. The `div.row` has a negative margin left and right of 15px, to compensate the 15px padding of the surrounding `div.container`. Because of the -15px margin, you can give your columns a padding of 15px and it appears as though they seamlessly align with the rest of your page. If we remove the negative margin, we get this:

[image]

Which is obviously not what we want. The usual approach would be to set the `padding-left` of the first column and the `padding-right` of the last column to 0 to align them. You could only imagine how complicated that would be with bigger grids that change depending on the viewport width.

[JSFiddle available here](http://jsfiddle.net/27r5he1b/).